# How big is the sum of smallest multinomial coefficients?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, binomial-coefficients

Given positive integers $n$ and $d$, let $S$ indicate the list of all $d$-tuples of non-negative integers $(c_1,\ldots,c_d)$ such that $c_1+\cdots+c_d=n$. Let $v_i$ be the value of the multinomial coefficient corresponding to $i$'th tuple in $S$, ie

$$v_i=\frac{n!}{c_1!\cdots c_d!}$$

What can we say about the sum of smallest coefficients, ie, the value of the following?

$$s(B)=\sum_{v_i < B} v_i$$

Motivation: upper bounds on multinomial tails would allow to give non-asymptotic error bounds for various learning algorithms

**Update: 09/03**
Here are all the relevant theoretical results I found so far. Let $B=\frac{n!}{c_1!\cdots c_d}$, $C=\max_i v_i$, $k=\min_i c_i$. Then for even n and $d=2$ the following are known to hold

$$s(B)<\frac{B}{C} 2^n$$
Proof under [Lemma 3.8.2](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/lovasz-binomial1.pdf) of Lovasz et al "Discrete Mathematics" (2003)

$$s(B)\le 2^n \exp(-\frac{(n/d-k)^2}{n-k})$$
Proof under [Theorem 5.3.2](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/lovasz-binomial2.pdf) of Lovasz et al "Discrete Mathematics" (2003)

$$s(B)\le 2B(\frac{n-(k-1)}{n-(2k-1)}-1)$$
Michael Lugo gives [outline](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n) of proof in another MO post

$$s(B)<2(\exp(n \log n - \sum_i c_i \log c_i)-B)$$
Proof under [Lemma 16.19](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/flum-binomial.pdf) of Flum et al *Parameterized Complexity Theory* (2006)

To be practically useful for my application, these bounds need to be tight for tails, ie, for sums that are less than $d^n/10$. Here's a plot of logarithm of bound/exact ratio for such sums. X-axis is monotonically related to B.

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/multinomial-bounds.png)

You can see that Michael Lugo's bound is by far the most accurate in that range.

Out of curiosity, I "plugged in" bounds above for sums of higher dimensional coefficients.

---

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/bounds-higherd2.png)

---

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/bounds-higherd3.png)

---

Mathematica [notebook](http://yaroslavvb.com/research/qr/mo-multinomials/mo-multinomials2.nb).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you at least have the following bound:

$$
s(B) \ \; \leq\ \; d^n \,-\, \exp \left( -2 \left( \frac{\ln B}{\ln ( n! ) - d\ln ( (n/d)! )} \right)^2  \right) \,d^{n} .
$$

You may want to do a little fiddling around with Stirling's approximation to reduce the denominator in the fraction a bit further, but I didn't want to weaken the bound more than necessary.

I found this by upper-bounding the probability that a multinomial distribution with uniform bin probabilities yields an "atypical" observation, using Hoeffding's inequality. "Atypical" is here defined in the information-theoretic sense: An atypical observation is one whose logarithmic probability falls short of the expected logarithmic probability over the whole distribution (see Cover and Thomas' *Elements of Information Theory*, particularly chapter 11).

Some more details:

Let $p$ be point probabilities for a multinomial distribution with uniform bin probabilities:

$$
p(c) \ =\ \left( \frac{n!}{c_1!c_2!\cdots c_d!} \right) d^{-n}.
$$

Notice that

$$
\ln p(c) \,+\, n\ln d \,\ =\ \ln \frac{n!}{c_1!c_2!\cdots c_d!},
$$

and thus

$$
\ln p(c) \,+\, n\ln d \;\leq\; \ln B \;\quad \iff\quad  \frac{n!}{c_1!c_2!\cdots c_d!} \;\leq\; B.
$$

Further, the entropy of the flat multinomial distribution is less than the entropy of $n$ samples from the flat categorical distribution with $d$ bins: The categorical includes order information as well as frequency information, while the multinomial only includes frequency information.

We thus have the following bound on the expected value of $-\ln p(c)$:

$$
E \left[\, -\ln p(c)\, \right] \ \leq\ 
n \cdot H\left( \frac{1}{d}, \frac{1}{d}, \ldots, \frac{1}{d}  \right)
\ =\ n\ln d,
$$

or in other words, $-n\ln d \leq E[\ln p(c)]$.

Further, the minimum and maximum values of the random variable $\ln p(c)$ are

$$
a
\; =\; 
\min_c \ln p(c)
\; =\; 
\ln \frac{n!}{n!\, 0!\, 0!\, \cdots\, 0!} d^{-n}
\; =\;
-n\ln d;
$$

$$
b
\; =\; 
\max_c \ln p(c)
\; =\; 
\ln \frac{n!}{(n/d)!\, (n/d)!\, \cdots\, (n/d)!} d^{-n}
\; =\;
\ln ( n! ) - d\ln ( (n/d)! ) - n\ln d.
$$

The squared distance between these two extremes is consequently

$$
(a - b)^2 \ =\ \left( \ln ( n! ) - d\ln ( (n/d)! ) \right)^2.
$$

We can now make the following comparisons:

\begin{eqnarray}
\Pr\left\{ \frac{n!}{c_1!c_2!\cdots c_d!} < B \right\}
& = &
\Pr\left\{ \ln p(c) \,+\, n\ln d < \ln B \right\}
\\
& \leq &
\Pr\left\{ \ln p(c) \,-\, E[\ln p(c)] < \ln B \right\}
\\
& = &
1 \,-\, \Pr\left\{ \ln p(c) \,-\, E[\ln p(c)] \geq \ln B \right\}
\\
& \leq &
1 \,-\, \exp \left( -2 \left( \frac{\ln B}{\ln ( n! ) - d\ln ( (n/d)! )} \right)^2 \right).
\end{eqnarray}

The first inequality follows from the fact that a proposition always has a lower probability than its logical consequences; the second is the application of Heoffding's inequality.

We thus have

$$
\Pr\left\{ \frac{n!}{c_1!c_2!\cdots c_d!} < B \right\}
\ \leq \ 
1\;-\;\exp \left( -2 \left( \frac{\ln B}{\ln ( n! ) - d\ln ( (n/d)! )} \right)^2 \right).
$$

By multiplying by $d^n$, we obtain the inequality stated above, since the probability of a sample from a flat multinomial distribution is equal to the corresponding multinomial coefficient divided by $d^n$.

Comment: It seems to me that all the occurences of $n/d!$ are typos for $(n/d)!$ (whatever that means when the ratio is not an integer).

Comment: I was omitting parentheses for readability, but if you think it suggests the wrong parsing, I should perhaps add them back in. About the integer issue: I skipped over that part to make the argument more transparent, but you could also use a Dirichlet-multinomial model instead, obtaining the same expected values.

Comment: Yes, I think you should put the brackets in place. $n/d!$ denotes $n$ divided by $d!$, and while that’s a bit unexpected expression, it only becomes clear later from the formula for $b$ what you really mean. (You might also want to fix Heoffding.)