# General bound for the number of subgroups of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I am interested in the following:

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Is there an explicit function $f$ such that 
$|s(G)| \leq f(n)$ for all $G$ and for all natural numbers $n$, where $s(G)$ denotes
the set of subgroups of $G$?

Comment: Yes. -- You can take $f(n) := 2^n$, which is the total number of subsets of $G$.


Comment: For n bigger than 4, you can even take a quarter of that. Gerhard "Except For Exceptions, Of Course" Paseman, 2013.06.03

Comment: It seems that among all groups of order $n$, the abelian group whose $p$-sylow subgroups are $p$-elementary has the largest number of subgroups and it is not difficult task to count them.

Comment: Maximal number of subgroups of a group with $n$ elements is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A018216

Comment: It seems that elementary abelian $p$-groups dominate. Since these groups have $\Theta (p^{\frac{(\log n)^2}{4}}) = \Theta(n^{c \log n})$, it is plausible that some sub-exponential bound of this sort holds for all finite groups, but I am not aware of any relevant work.

Comment: My comment above is wrong because according to the link @Gerry-Myerson sent, the symmetric group $S_3$ has $6$ subgroups and the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/{6\mathbb{Z}}$ has $4$ subgroups.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A non-identity subgroup of a group of order $n$ can be generated by $\log_{2}(n)$ or fewer elements. There is quite a lot of duplication, but if you count the number of subsets of $G$ of cardinality at most $\log_{2}(n),$ you will have an upper bound (which could be made more precise with more care) and the case of elementary Abelian $2$-groups show that such a bound is of the right general shape if it is to cover all groups of all orders.

To be more precise, this gives an upper bound of approximately $\log_{2}(n)n^{\log_{2}(n)}$ for the total number of subgroups of a group of order $n,$ which is generically rather generous. On the other hand, the number of subgroups of an elementary Abelian group of order $n= 2^{r}$ is close to $\sum_{i=0}^{r}2^{i(r-i)},$ so generally larger that $n^{log_{2}(n)/4}.$

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, did you intend "of an *elementary abelian* group" instead?


Answer (score 15):

A theorem of [Borovik, Pyber and Shalev](http://www.ams.org/tran/1996-348-09/S0002-9947-96-01665-0/S0002-9947-96-01665-0.pdf) (Corollary 1.6) shows that the number of subgroups of a group $G$ of order $n=\lvert G\rvert$ is bounded by $n^{(\frac{1}{4}+o(1)) \log_2(n)}$. This is essentially best possible, cf. Geoff Robinsons answer above.

Answer (score 10):

There is a variant of this question which has received a lot of attention and which may be of interest here: namely how many **maximal** subgroups a finite group may have. In this context the relevant conjecture is due to Wall:

> **Conjecture** The number of maximal subgroups of a finite group G is less than the order of G.

This has been the subject of much study with the landmark work (until recently) being the result of [Liebeck, Pyber and Shalev](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2360145) which states that the number of maximal subgroups is at most $c|G|^{3/2}$ where $c$ is an absolute constant. They also show that the conjecture is true if the group G is simple, up to a finite number of exceptions.

In very recent work it has now been shown that Wall's conjecture is **not true** in general. An account of the demise of the conjecture can be found [here](http://aimath.org/news/wallsconjecture/wall.conjecture). (This is not a paper, rather it's a very engaging description of the research which resulted in counter-examples being found.)

In light of this development, the bound $c|G|^{3/2}$ mentioned above assumes greater importance. Although, as the linked document mentions, it is likely that the index $\frac32$ can be reduced a great deal.

Whether one can deduce bounds on the number of non-maximal subgroups from the results of Liebeck, Pyber and Shalev, I don't know...

Comment: The second link is now dead.

Comment: Maybe this: https://aimath.org/news/wallsconjecture/wall.conjecture.pdf is a good substitute for the dead link?

Comment: @user2520938, yes, that is the one!

Answer (score 5):

Can refine Stefan Kohl's suggestion by taking subsets containing the identity element of $G$  and of cardinality dividing $n$.

So the upper bound is $\sum_{d>1,  d| n}^n  {n-1\choose d-1}$

Comment: By considering inverses, you can cut the figure down further unless there are a lot of elements of order 2.  For that case you can look at the subproblem of counting vector spaces over F_2.  Gerhard "Which Has Already Been Studied" Paseman, 2013.06.03

Answer (score 3):

In a similar vein to Geoff Robinson's answer, observe that any proper subgroup of a group of order $n$ can be generated by at most $\Omega(n) - 1$ elements, where $\Omega$ counts the number of prime factors (with multiplicity) of $n$. This is tight, with equality in the case of a product of prime cyclic groups.

This gives an upper bound of:

$$ \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{\Omega(n) - 1} + 1$$

subgroups, where the final $+ 1$ includes $G$ itself. Now we can invoke Michael Lugo's strict upper bound from https://mathoverflow.net/a/17236/39521 to obtain a closed-form upper bound:

$$ |s(G)| \leq \left\lceil \binom{n}{\Omega(n) - 1} \dfrac{n - \Omega(n) + 2}{n - 2 \Omega(n) + 2} \right\rceil \leq \dfrac{2 \times n^{\Omega(n) - 1}}{(\Omega(n) - 1)!}$$

Note that this is tight infinitely often: in the case where $n = p$ is prime (so $G = C_p$), we get:

$$ \dfrac{2 \times p^0}{0!} = 2 $$

where the two subgroups are the trivial group and $G$ itself.

Comment: I think that if $G$ is a direct product of cyclic groups of distinct prime orders, every subgroup of $G$ is cyclic, so this seems be different from that suggested by your second sentence when there are three or more different primes (and $G$ is cyclic of squarefree order). Also, by a theorem of Guralnick and Lucchini (which uses classification of finite simple groups), that if $|G| = \prod_{i=1}^{m}p_{i}^{a_{i}}$ with the $p_{i}$ distinct primes,  and $a_{j} = {\rm max}\{a_{i}\}$, then each subgroup of $G$ is generated by at most $a_{j}+1$ elements,  usually less that $\Omega(n)-1$