# A good upper-bound for the cardinal of an interval of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-theory, computational-group-theory

This post is a *relative version* of [General bound for the number of subgroups of a finite group](https://mathoverflow.net/q/132675/34538)

Let $[H,G]$ be a interval of finite groups with $|G:H| = n$.

*Question:* What is a good upper-bound of $|[H,G]|$, as a function of $n$?

If $H=\{ e\}$, then the best possible upper-bound is essentially $n^{(\frac{1}{4}+o(1)) \log_2(n)}$ ([here](http://www.ams.org/tran/1996-348-09/S0002-9947-96-01665-0/S0002-9947-96-01665-0.pdf), Corollary 1.6).
Should we expect the same in general?

There is an OEIS page for the maximal cardinal of a subgroup lattice for a group of order $n$: [A018216](http://oeis.org/A018216)
1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 16, 6, 8, 2, 16, 2, 10, 4, 67, 2, 28, 2, 22, 10, 14, 2, 54, 8, 16, 28, 28, 2, 28, 2, 374, 4, 20, 4, 78, 2, 22, 16, 76, 2, 36, 2, 40, 12, 26, 2, 236, 10, 64, 4, 46, 2, 212, 14, 98, 22, 32, 2, 80, 2, 34, 36, 2825, 4, 52, 2, 58, 4, 52, 2, 272

I didn't find an OEIS page for the maximal cardinal of an interval of finite groups, at index $n$.
This should be computable for the indices $<32$, using GAP or MAGMA.

*Remark*: Because an element $K \in [H,G]$ admits a unique partition by cosets $Hg$, we have:
$$|[H,G]| < \sum_{k \mid n} {n \choose k}$$
See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1808549/84284) for a discussion on the estimate of this sum.
We have slightly better with $\sum_{k>1,  k|n}^n  {n-1\choose k-1}$.

Comment: A pretty good estimate is (n-1) choose ((n/p) - 1) for p the smallest prime factor of n.  This is because sum of n choose i for i ranging from 0 to j is dominated by (n choose j)( 1 +  j/(n-2j+1)), which is less than (3/2)(n choose j) when 4j is at most n. Even if n  is divisible by twelve, the sum is less than (n choose (n/4))/2 +  n choose n/2 + n choose n/3 + n choose n/4.  Gerhard "How Close Do You Need?" Paseman, 2016.06.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: As close as possible. We are more interested in an estimate, as for the full subgroup lattice, of the form $n^{(\frac{1}{4}+o(1)) \log_2(n)}$.

Comment: Is it even clear that the interval has at least (n-1) choose ((n/p)-1) subgroups?  If so, then the answer will be close to this value.  Otherwise I suspect the sum over k dividing n of n choose k will be too far off.  Gerhard "Binomial Coefficients Are Big Hammers" Paseman, 2016.06.03.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1331326/84284

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chain in $[H,G]$ has length $\leq\Omega(|G:H|)$, where $\Omega$ denotes the number of prime factors counted with multiplicity. If $H=H_0<H_1<\dots<H_k=G$ is a maximal chain, then there are elements $g_1, \ldots, g_k$, such that $H_i=\langle H_{i-1}, g_i\rangle$. If $g_iH=g_i'H$, then $\langle g_i H_{i-1}\rangle = \langle g'_i H_{i-1}\rangle$, hence, the number of subgroup chains is bounded above by the number of sequences of cosets of $H$ in $G$, of length $\leq\Omega(|G:H|)$.  Hence for $n=|G:H|$ the number of subgroups is $\leq \Omega(n) \frac{n!}{(n-\Omega(n))!} $ $ \le\Omega(n)  n^{\Omega(n)}$ $\leq \log_2(n) n^{\log_2(n)} $ $ \leq n^{1+\log_2(n)}$.

To gain the missing factor 4 in the exponent you have to use the fact that there are different choices for the $g_i$, and that a group $K$ can occur in many different chains. However, this will be quite difficult. If you look at $C_p^n$, you see that most subgroups have index $\approx p^{n/2}$, thus a local argument will not work.

Answer (score 2):

The same reasoning applies when $H \lhd G$ as when $H = 1$, so when $H \lhd G$ the general bound can't be improved. Since the worst case of the general bound occurs when $G$ is Abelian, you can't really expect any improvement (if $H \lhd G$ and $G/H$ is an elementary Abelian $2$-group, the number of subgroups between $H$ and $G$ will be close to $n^{\frac{\log_{2}(n)}{4}}$). In any case, an argument like that given in my answer to the previous question shows that there is a general upper bound of around $\log_{2}(n) n^{\log_{2}(n)}$ (this is similar to, but cruder than, the argument in the above answer of Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta).