# Is there an interval of finite groups, at index n, with strictly more elements than the subgroup lattice of any group, of order n?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-theory, computational-group-theory, magma

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathcal{L}(G)$ its subgroup lattice.
Let $s(n):= max\{|\mathcal{L}(G)| \text{ for } |G|=n \}$.

There is an OEIS page for the sequence $s(n)$: [A018216](http://oeis.org/A018216)
1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 16, 6, 8, 2, 16, 2, 10, 4, 67, 2, 28, 2, 22, 10, 14, 2, 54, 8, 16, 28, 28, 2, 28, 2, 374, 4, 20, 4, 78, 2, 22, 16, 76, 2, 36, 2, 40, 12, 26, 2, 236, 10, 64, 4, 46, 2, 212, 14, 98, 22, 32, 2, 80, 2, 34, 36, 2825, 4, 52, 2, 58, 4, 52, 2, 272

Now let $[H,G]$ be an interval of finite groups and $|[H,G]|$ its cardinal.
Let $t(n):= max\{|[H,G]| \text{ for } |G:H|=n \}$.

I didn't find an OEIS page for the sequence $t(n)$.
This is computable for the indices $<32$, using GAP or MAGMA (I've no access to, currently)

**Question**: Is there an integer $n$ such that $t(n)>s(n)$?

*Remark*: If we observe that $\forall n \ t(n)=s(n)$, then a proof of this fact would answer [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/240351/34538).
 Else, I'm interested in the smallest counter-example.

*Remark*: Alexander Hulpke has checked that $t(n)=s(n)$, $\forall n \le 47$ (see comment below).

Comment: A somewhat [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1331326/11619). Mostly adding this, because Gerry and Derek give more links there.

Comment: Could you please add a definition for an interval of finite groups?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: $[H,G] = \{K \ | \ H \le K \le G\}$.

Comment: I just verified (using the lists of transitive groups in degrees 32-47 due to Derek Holt) that $t(n)=s(n)$ for $n\le 47$. I would be very surprised if a group could have more block systems than a regular abelian group, but that is gut feeling and no proof.