# What properties characterize the function $L(x) = x+\exp(x) \log(x)$?

Tags: finite-groups, special-functions, stochastic-matrices, matrix-exponential

As might be known, the function $L(x) = x+\exp(x)\log(x)$ plays a prominent role in the Lagarias formulation of the Riemann hypothesis:

$$\sigma(n) \le H_n + \exp(H_n) \log(H_n)$$

My question is, what "abstract" properties does this function have (like for example the $\exp$-function has the property $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$) and do these properties characterize this function?

Thanks for your help! (Also I am not sure how to properly tag this question)

Related:
[A group theoretic interpretation of Lagarias inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330077/a-group-theoretic-interpretation-of-lagarias-inequality)

**Edit**:
Another related question:
Dou you know of any other situation where the function $L(x)$ occurs?
That would also be quite interesting!

**Second Edit**:
I found a very exciting connection to "Logarithmic numbers" as defined by J. M. Gandhi:

http://oeis.org/A002741

The numbers $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} L(x)$ at $x=1$ are related to the Logarithmic numbers as defined by Gandhi.

There are two papers by Gandhi, on this topic:

http://oeis.org/A002741/a002741.pdf which is a little bit hard to read because it is scanned, and
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1966.11970871 where there is made a connection to $\sigma(n)$ and the logarithmic numbers.

**Third edit (18.05.2019)**:
I think I found a very interesting property which seems to always hold:

If $A$ is a normal ($A^TA=AA^T$) and non-singular matrix and such that $\frac{1}{|A|}\cdot A$ is a doubly stochastic, positive matrix, then we have:

$$L(|A|) = |L(A)|$$
and $L(A)$ is a normal, non-singular matrix such that $\frac{1}{|L(A)|}\cdot L(A)$is doubly stochastic, positive matrix.
where $|.|$ denotes the spectral norm.

To be more concrete I will tell how I construct the matrix for a given finite group $G$:

Let $\rho$ be the regular representation of $G$. $S \subset G$ a generating set, $|g| := |g|_S=$ word length with respect to $S$. Then I construct such a matrix, where we have some ordering $g_i$ of the group $G$:

$$ a_{i,j} = \frac{1}{1+|g_i g_j^{-1}|}$$

This is a group matrix as defined by Dedekind and Frobenius. Let $H_G:= \sum_{g \in G} \frac{1}{|g|+1}$ be the harmonic number associated to $S$ and $G$.

Here are my conjectures concerning this matrix some of which I can prove:

1. $H_G = |A|$ [proved by Perron-Frobenius theorem]
2. (If 1. is true, then by definition of $A$ we must have that $1/H_G A = 1/|A| A $ is a doubly stochastic matrix [thats clear by 1. and definition of $A_G$.]
3. $A = \sum_{g \in G} \frac{1}{1+|g|} \rho(g)$ is the Birkhoff-Neunmann decomposition induced by the doubly stochastic matrix [proved by definition of $A_G$ and $\rho$]
4. Using 2. I can prove that $A$ is a normal matrix
5. $A$ is non-singular. [that remains mysterious]

My updated question is, if (any of) this can be proven (or if it is known, then any reference would also be nice)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: One way to characterize it is $x L'' - (2 x - 1) L' + (x - 1) L =x^2 - 3 x + 1$, $L(1)=1$, $L''(1)=e$

Comment: @MattF. I think you forgot the condition $L'(1) = e+1$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: WolframAlpha confirms the uniqueness of the characterization I proposed: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+L%27%27%5Bx%5D+-+(2x-1)L%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+(x-1)L%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+x%5E2-3+x%2B1,+L%5B1%5D%3D%3D1,+L%27%27%5B1%5D%3D%3DE.  The alternative suggestion has $L(1)=e$.

Comment: @MattF. You are right. The uniqueness of your characterization is given.

Comment: Can you clarify your third edit? What is the Euclidean norm of a matrix? Frobenius/Hilbert-Schmidt norm? Or operator/spectral norm? Or something else? I've tried a few guesses, but numerics quickly disprove $L(|A|) = |L(A)|$ for every guess that I've made for what the norm should be.

Comment: @NathanialJohnston: Spectral norm. Can you give your examples? The matrices I am looking at seem to have this property.

Comment: Oh I see. You're right, that property holds then simply by usual functional calculus. $|A|$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$, whereas $|L(A)|$ is the largest eigenvalue of $L(A)$. But the eigenvalues of $L(A)$ are just $L$ applied to the eigenvalues of $A$. Since $L$ is monotone, the largest eigenvalue of $L(A)$ is just $L(|A|)$. This works as long as $A$ has positive real eigenvalues (but if that's not the case then even defining $L(A)$ in the first place is going to be somewhat icky, so I hope it's OK).

Comment: @NathanielJonston: Ok, thanks for your comment. Would you mind writing your comment in a bit more detail as an answer? (If it is not asked too much than maybe with reference?)

Comment: @NathanielJohnston: Some of the matrices I am considering do not have real eigenvalues, but still $L(|A|) = |L(A)|$.

Comment: @orgesleka -- It definitely can't be true if you allow arbitrary complex eigenvalues. Try the diagonal matrix $A$ with diagonal entries $1$ and $i$. Then $L(|A|) = 1$ but $|L(A)| \approx 2.27$.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston: Ok, I will update the question, with further properties.

Comment: I think (from the last paragraph of the article due to Lagarias) that maybe it is interesting consider $l(x)=e^x\log x$. For $L(x)$ or $l(x)$, maybe can be interesting to state Möbius inversion, and related asymptotic formulas, section *Generalizations* of the Wikipedia *Möbius inversion formula* as starting point. I refer also (section 3) of Manuel Benito and Luis M. Navas and Juan Luis Varona, *Möbius inversion from the point of view of arithmetical semigroup flows*, Biblioteca de la Revista Matemática Iberoamericana, Proceedings of the Segundas Jornadas de Teoría de Números (Madrid, 2007).

Comment: @user142929 thanks for your comment