# Partial sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For some integer $z \ge 2$ and large integer $n$ and $ t=\lceil \log n\rceil $, what is an approximate value for the following partial binomial sum?
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-t} \binom{n}{i}z^i  .$$

Another related problem for the same parameters is approximating
$$ \sum_{i=n/t}^n \binom{n}{i}z^i   .$$

Thanks.

Comment: This is close to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

Comment: In both cases the sum is asymptotic to $(1+z)^n$ with great precision, since you have given almost all of the binomial summation.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay true! I did not notice that $t$ is so small and took it to be arbitrary!

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thanks. Do you any reference or hint for its proof?

Comment: You can just be crude and say ${n \choose n-m} \leq n^m$ in this range. Thus the sum of the missing terms is at most $t n^t z^n$, which is exponentially smaller than $(1+z)^n$.

Comment: The largest term is at $k=nx/(1+x)$.  If $f(n)/\sqrt{n}\to\infty$, the terms with $|k -nx/(1+x)| \le f(n)$ give most of the sum.  So any interval of summation that includes those important values of $k$ will be asymptotic to $(1+x)^n$.