# Counting Regions in Hyperplane Arranglements

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, hyperplane-arrangements

Consider the following:

> 1) How many connected regions can $n$ hyperplanes form in $\mathbb R^d$?
>
> 2) What if the set of hyperplanes are homogeneous?
>
> 3) Given a set of $n$ **pairs** of hyperplanes, such that each pair is parallel, what is the maximum number of regions that can be formed?

I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409518/how-many-resulting-regions-if-we-partition-mathbbrm-with-n-hyperplanes/409642#409642),[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843834/trying-to-understand-formula-for-counting-regions-of-hyperplane-arrangements-in?rq=1) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n/17261#17261) that the answer to (1) is
$$f(d,n)=\sum_{i=0}^d {n \choose i}$$

However I find it non-trivial to generalize the proof of $\mathbb R^2$ that was provided to $\mathbb R^d$ (without using "lower"/"upper" descriptions). Is there any "nice" way to show it recursively?

Q3 is what I'm really after.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is all explained in e.g. Stanley's notes on hyperplane arrangements: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/arrangements/arr.html

Comment: @SamHopkins: You just went ahead of me. :-)

Comment: The proof (page 18) is not as clear as one may think :)

Comment: For the proof on page 18, see the errata at http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/arrangements/errata.pdf.

Comment: Much better now :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Radon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon's_theorem)
to show that homogeneous hyperplanes $w$ can shatter (i.e., assign all possible sign sequences via $x\mapsto\text{sign}(<w,x>)$ at most $d$ points.
This is an upper bound on the [VC-dimension on hyperplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) (which turns out to be tight).
Then use the [Sauer-Shelah lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauer%E2%80%93Shelah_lemma) to bound the number of *behaviors* that the hyperplanes can attain on $n$ points

That accounts for the formula $\sum_{i=1}^d {n\choose i}$.

As for pairs of hyperplanes, I'll use a very crude bound for VC-dimension of intersections of pairs of sets from a VC-class of dimension $d$, see Theorem 3.6 in [Kearns-Vazirani](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-computational-learning-theory)
or [this paper](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2010/711/lectures/0081.pdf) by Baum and Haussler, to get that the VC-dimension of the collection of pairs of hyperplanes in $d$ dimensions is at most $20d$. You can then apply Sauer-Shelah to this new value of  VC-dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have $n$ sets of $r$ parallel hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^d$
in generic position. There are $r^k\binom nk$ ways to choose $k$ of
them that intersect in a flat $x$. The interval from $\hat{0}$ to $x$
in the intersection poset is a boolean algebra, so the Mobius function
is given by $\mu(\hat{0},x)=\pm 1$. Thus by Zaslavsky's theorem, the
number of regions is $\sum_{k=0}^d r^k\binom nk$.

Comment: For a much less elegant proof of this formula (by people who don't know any theorems) see Lemma 3 in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03181