# Complete graph coloring with cycle restriction

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

The following question is probably open (It was posted on AoPS a long time ago, but no one has a solution)

We have a complete graph with $n$ vertices. Each edge is colored in one of $c$ colors such that no two incident edges have the same color. Assume that no two cycles of the same size have the same set of colors. Prove $c$ is at least $n^2/50000000$.

I have no idea how to solve this. Helps will be really appreciate

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see, this question has a simple solution.

Let's limit ourselves to Hamiltonian cycles, and forget about the constraint that the coloring is legal.

**Theorem:**
Let $c$ be an edge-coloring of $K_n$ such that no two Hamiltonian cycles have the same set of colors. Then $c\geq (1+o(1))\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^2$.

**Proof:** There are $(n-1)!/2$ Hamiltonian cycles, and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{c}{i}$ subsets of $c$ of size at most $n$. As each Hamiltonian cycle corresponds to a different such subset, we get the inequality
$$
(n-1)!/2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{c}{i}.
$$ 
Recalling that $(n-1)!/2=((1+o(1))\left(\frac{n}{e}\right))^n$ and that (for $c>2n$, which we can assume here) $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{c}{i}=((1+o(1))\left(\frac{c \cdot e}{n}\right))^n$, we have
$$
((1+o(1))\left(\frac{n}{e}\right))^n\leq\left(\frac{c \cdot e}{n}\right)^n ,
$$
which yields the theorem.

Comment: Just a minor inessential point: the most usual convention these days is that $K^n$ has $\frac12(n-1)!$ Hamilton cycles=(undirected simple 2-regular spanning subgraphs), *not* $(n-1)!$. Just check your formula for $K^3$, which has 1 Hamilton cycle only. And it is *this* convention which is the appropriate one for your proof, since the idea of a *direction* of Hamilton cycles is unrelated to the idea of counting not-necessarily-proper edge-colorings thereof.

Comment: Just to add a quantity of useful context and interconnectedness: a relevant MO-thread on 'initial sums of the familiar sum $\sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\binom{n}{i}=2^n$ ' is [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n). Estimating such sums is essential to carrying through Zur Luria's proof.

Comment: While your proof seems essentially correct, I personally think the use of $(n-1)!$ instead of $\frac12(n-1)!$, and moreover the use of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{c}{i}$ instead of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{c}{i}$ (after all, a Hamilton cycle in $K^n$ has $n$ edges, not $n-1$) are almost-wrong, or puzzling at least. Note that from the correct terms there results a *weaker* inequality, namely $\frac12(n-1)!\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{c}{i}$, which is weaker in that it has both a *smaller* small side and a *larger* large side. Your argument seems to get through though. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree with everything that you have said. I will make the changes.

Comment: (This is perhaps naive, but) out of interest, does the inequality $\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\leq \sum_{i=1}^n{c\choose i}$ hold for general values of $c$? Or just those corresponding to edge colourings?