# Prove positivity of rational functions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, elementary-proofs

We say a rational function $F(z)$ is positive if the coefficients of its Maclaurin expansion, in the variable $z$, are non-negative.

In this context, let
$$F_r(z):=\frac{1 - 2z + z^r - (1 - z)^r}{(1 - z)^{r - 1}(1 - 2z)}.$$

Is the following true? Note: $F_2(z)=0$ and $F_3(z)$ is easier to manage.

> **QUESTION.** For $r\geq4$, each of the rational functions $F_r(z)$ is positive.

**Example.** After simplifications, $F_4(z)=\frac{2z}{(1-z)^2}$.

Comment: If I had the power to change definitions, I would call $F(z)$ as above non-negative.

Comment: @HenrikRüping: In fact, their coefficients for $r\geq 3$ are positive. So, it's ok to call them positive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that
$$F_r(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^{r-1}} - \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^k$$
and therefore for $r\geq 4$ and $n\geq 1$, we have
\begin{split}
[x^n]\ F_r(z) &= \binom{n+r-2}{r-2} - \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \\
& = \binom{n+r-2}{r-2} - \binom{n-1}{r-2} - \binom{n-1}{r-3} - \sum_{k=1}^{r-3} \binom{n-1}{n-k} \\
&\geq \binom{n+r-2}{r-2} - \binom{n}{r-2} - \sum_{k=1}^{r-3} \binom{n-1+r-3-k}{n-k} \\
&= \binom{n+r-2}{r-2} - \binom{n}{r-2} - \binom{n+r-4}{r-3} \\
&\geq \binom{n+r-2}{r-2} - \binom{n+r-4}{r-2} - \binom{n+r-4}{r-3} \\
&= \binom{n+r-3}{r-3}\\
&> 0.
\end{split}

---

**ADDED.** The above bound implies a stronger statement: for $r\geq 2$ the function
$$F_r(z) + 1 - \frac{1}{(1-z)^{r-2}}$$
is non-negative.

Comment: $\binom{n+r-2}{r-2} - \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ is non-negative also by a simple combinatorial reasons: take $n-1$ boys and $r-1$ girls and choose $r-2$ children from them: if you fix the chosen $k-1$ boys, you may always add $r-k-1$ girls to them.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Essentially this argument equivalent to the use of Vandermonde's identity: $$\binom{n+r-2}{r-2} = \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{r-1}{r-1-k}$$ and noticing that $\binom{r-1}{r-1-k}\geq 1$. With a bit of extra effort I got a bit stronger bound.