# sum of binomial coefficient approximation by geometric series

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I follow a subject almost like this link:
[Sum of 'the first k' binomial coefficients for fixed $N$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n)
$$
f(N,k) = \sum^{k}_{i=0} \binom{N}{i} .
$$
Michael Lugo suggest a way with geometric series :
$$\sum^{k}_{i=0}  \binom{N}{i} \leqslant   \binom{N}{i} \cdot \frac{ n-k+1 }{(n-2\cdot k+1)}\label{1}\tag{ML} $$

Using Pascal's rule , $\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k} $ , I compress the terms to obtain others series
$$
\begin{split}
\sum^{k}_{i=0} \binom{N}{i} & = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} +  \binom{n}{k-2} + \binom{n}{k-3} + \ldots \\
&= \binom{n+1}{k} + \binom{n+1}{k-2}+\dots\;. 
\end{split}$$
This implies
$$
\begin{split}
\dfrac{ \sum^{k}_{i=0} \binom{N}{i}   }{ \binom{n+1}{k} } & =  1 + \frac{(k-1) \cdot k}{(n-k+2) \cdot (n-k+3)} \\ 
& \quad  + \frac{(k-3) \cdot (k-2) \cdot (k-1) \cdot k}{(n-k+2) \cdot (n-k+3) \cdot (n-k+4) \cdot (n-k+5)}\\ 
& \quad +  \frac{(k-5) \cdot (k-4) \cdot (k-3) \cdot (k-2) \cdot (k-1) \cdot k}{(n-k+2) \cdot (n-k+3) \cdot (n-k+4) \cdot (n-k+5) \cdot (n-k+6) \cdot (n-k+7)}  + \ldots\\ &\approx  \frac{ (n-k+2) \cdot (n-k+3)}{(n+2) \cdot (n-2\cdot k+3)}  
\end{split}
$$
the term of the series is $((k-1)\cdot k)/((n-k+2)\cdot(n-k+3)))$ so:
$$ \sum^{k}_{i=0} \binom{N}{i}   \approx  \binom{n+1}{k} \cdot\frac{ (n-k+2) \cdot (n-k+3)}{(n+2) \cdot (n-2\cdot k+3)} \label{2}\tag{F1}
$$
If we start at the third terms we have:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{ \sum^{k}_{i=0} \binom{N}{i}   }{ \binom{n+1}{k} } & =  1+ \frac{(k-1) \cdot k}{(n-k+2) \cdot (n-k+3)}  \cdot   \Bigg( 1 +  \frac{(k-3) \cdot (k-2)}{(n-k+4) \cdot (n-k+5)} \\
&\quad+  \frac{(k-5) \cdot (k-4) \cdot (k-3) \cdot (k-2)}{(n-k+4) \cdot (n-k+5) \cdot (n-k+6) \cdot (n-k+7)} 
 + \ldots \Bigg )\\ 
&  \approx   1 +  \frac{(k-1) \cdot k}{(n-k+2) \cdot (n-k+3)}  \cdot   \frac{(n-k+4) \cdot (n-k+5)}{(n+2) \cdot (n-2 \cdot k+7)}  
\end{split} \label{3}\tag{F2}
$$
We can separate the series  into 2 series, by taking only one terms on two which give:
$$
\begin{split}
 & \frac{1 }{\binom{n+1}{k}} \cdot\Bigg(  \binom{n+1}{k} +  \binom{n+1}{k-4} +  \binom{n+1}{k-8}  + \ldots \Bigg) \\
& = 
1+ \frac{(k-3)\cdot(k-2)\cdot(k-1)\cdot k}{(n-k+2)\cdot(n-k+3)\cdot(n-k+4)\cdot(n-k+5)} \\
&\quad + \frac{(k-7)\cdot(k-6)\cdot(k-5)\cdot(k-4)\cdot(k-3)\cdot(k-2)\cdot(k-1)\cdot k}{[(n-k+2)\cdot(n-k+3)\cdot(n-k+4)\cdot(n-k+5)\cdot(n-k+6)\cdot(n-k+7)\cdot(n-k+8)\cdot(n-k+9)]} \\  
&\approx  \frac{(n-k+2)\cdot(n-k+3)\cdot(n-k+4)\cdot(n-k+5)}{(n+2)\cdot(n-2\cdot k+5)\cdot(n^2-2\cdot k\cdot n+7\cdot n+2\cdot k^2-10\cdot k+12)} 
\end{split}$$
thus
$$ 
\begin{split}
& \frac{1 }{\binom{n+1}{k}} \cdot\Bigg(  \binom{n+1}{k-2} +  \binom{n+1}{k-6} +  \binom{n+1}{k-10}  + \ldots\bigg)  \\
& = 
\frac{(k-1)\cdot k}{(n-k+2)\cdot(n-k+3)} \\
& \quad \cdot \Bigg( 1 + \frac{(k-5)\cdot(k-4)\cdot (k-3)\cdot(k-2)}{(n-k+4)\cdot(n-k+5)\cdot(n-k+6)\cdot(n-k+7)} \\ 
& \quad +
\frac{(k-9)\cdot(k-8)\cdot(k-7)\cdot(k-6)}{(n-k+4)\cdot(n-k+5)\cdot(n-k+6)} \\
& \quad\cdot\frac{(k-5)\cdot(k-4)\cdot(k-3)\cdot(k-2)}{(n-k+7)\cdot(n-k+8)\cdot(n-k+9)\cdot(n-k+10)\cdot(n-k+11)} + \ldots \Bigg) \\
& \approx \frac{(k-1)\cdot k}{(n-k+2)\cdot(n-k+3)} \\
& \quad \cdot \frac{(n-k+4)\cdot(n-k+5)\cdot(n-k+6)\cdot(n-k+7)}{(n+2)\cdot(n-2\cdot k+9)\cdot(n^2-2\cdot k\cdot n+11\cdot n+2\cdot k^2-18\cdot k+40)} 
\end{split}
$$
and this implies
$$ 
\begin{split}
f(N,k) & \approx  \binom{n+1}{k} \\
 & \quad \cdot \Bigg( 
 \frac{(n-k+2)\cdot (n-k+3)\cdot(n-k+4)\cdot(n-k+5)}{(n+2)\cdot(n-2\cdot k+5)\cdot (n^2-2\cdot k\cdot n+7\cdot n+2\cdot k^2-10\cdot k+12)}\\
& \quad + \frac{(k-1)\cdot k}{(n-k+2)\cdot (n-k+3)}\\
& \quad \cdot \frac{(n-k+4)\cdot (n-k+5)\cdot (n-k+6)\cdot(n-k+7)}{(n+2)\cdot(n-2\cdot k+9)\cdot(n^2-2\cdot k\cdot n+11\cdot n+2\cdot k^2-18\cdot k+40)} \Bigg)
\end{split}\label{4}\tag{F3}
$$
This series are sharper, using the calculator PARI/GP , i found the following relative errors:

| (N,k) | (100,20) | (100,40) | (100,50) | (1000,200) | (1000,400) | (1000,500) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \ref{1} | 0.00626 | 0.10740 | 6.51962 | 0.00069 | 0.01563 | 23.65358 |
| \ref{2} | 0.000784 | 0.05096 | 1.629873 | 0.000107 | 0.0096452 | 7.25888 |
| \ref{3} | 2.700 E-5 | 0.012036 | 0.371743 | 6.3169 E-6 | 0.0039623 | 2.623599 |
| \ref{4} | 3.810 E-6 | 0.0086979 | 0.41073 | 1.338 E-6 | 0.003315 | 2.913452 |

But my problem is that for any approximation when $k \to N/2$ the error is too large, as you can see, because the geometric term converge to one.

I am seeking for an approximate formulation of the sum of binomial coefficient for fixed $N$, with sharp bound, to be differentiable if needed. Can we transform the series to be valid when $k\to N/2 $?

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried exploiting the known values $f(2N, N-1) = 2^{2N-1} - \frac{1}{2} \binom{2N}{N}$ and $f(2N + 1, N) = 2^{2N}$ and handling central ranges by subtracting from / adding to these offsets?

Comment: Essentially the same question as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202.

Comment: It may be worth it to check bounds from my answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/422395

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: I'm looking for very sharp approximation. I check some bounds given in  mathoverflow.net/questions/17202 . Jean Gallier and Lovasz bounds are low only when k $\approx$ N/2,  Chernoff's bound is slightly badder. Do you want a table to compare the different bounds and see the evolution ?

Comment: @Max-Alekseyev , i look your answer but it's too high for my purpose.

Comment: @peter-taylor, i don't see how to continue with these values.

Comment: @tess35 : What do you mean by "very sharp approximation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$According to the Theorem on p. 129 of [Uspensky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070667357), for all $n\ge100$ and all integers $k$ we have
$$f(n,k)=2^n(\Phi(z_{n,k})+\ep_{n,k}), \tag{10}\label{10}$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function,
$$z_{n,k}:=\frac2{\sqrt n}\Big(k-\frac{n-1}2\Big),$$
and
$$|\ep_{n,k}|<\frac{0.52}n+e^{-3\sqrt n/4}.$$

In particular, if $k\approx n/2$, then $\Phi(z_{n,k})\approx1/2$ and hence the relative error of the approximation of $f(n,k)$ by $2^n\Phi(z_{n,k})$ is no more than $\approx\frac{1.04}n+2e^{-3\sqrt n/4}$.

Here is the table of the actual values of the relative errors
$$e_{n,k}:=\frac{f_{n,k}}{2^n\Phi(z_{n,k})}-1$$
of the approximation $2^n\Phi(z_{n,k})$ of $f_{n,k}$ provided by formula \eqref{10} for $n=100$ and $k=30,40,50,60,70$:

[image]

Here is also the graph $\{(k,e_{n,k})\colon30\le k\le70\}$ for $n=100$:

[image]

---

Approximations of $f(n,k)$ with relative errors $o(1/n^p)$ for (say) $k=n/2+O(\sqrt n)$ for arbitrary real $p>0$ follow immediately from asymptotic expansions of the probability $f(n,k)/2^n$ (that a binomial random variable with parameters $n,1/2$ takes a value $\le k$) such as [Theorem 6, Ch. VI](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65809-9) in Petrov's book; the original source of this theorem is the [paper by Osipov](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1114057).

Comment: I think i will use this result. Could you elaborate on the last paragraph? Is it this theorem page 171 , https://books.google.fr/books?id=zSDqCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false ?  $Ur(x) = \Phi(x) + \sum^{[r]-2}_{v=1} \frac{Q_v(x)}{n^{v/2}}$   ?

Comment: @tess35 : Yes, it is Theorem 6 on p. 171.

Comment: @tess35 : I have added a reference to the original source of that Theorem 6.

Comment: Could you explain what is the $ \alpha_v $ coefficient ? If I understand,  for $\nu$ = 1 , k1 = 1 , k2 =0... so K=1, for $\nu$ =2 , (k1=2,k2=0, K=2), (k1=0,k2=1,K=1) . I work on thermodynamic, so i search something like $ \mid (f_{true}-f_{approx})/f_{true} \mid \leq 0.1 $. , to differentiate or transform.

Comment: @tess35 : Are you referring here to Osipov's paper? There $\alpha_l=EX_n^l$, as defined just before formula (2) in that paper. I gave you references to Petrov and Osipov only because you were talking about some "very sharp approximation". However, in your latter comment you seem to be talking about the relative error being just $\le0.1$. Then Uspensky's result, stated in the first paragraph of my answer, will be more than enough, as it gives you a simple approximation with a relative error $<0.012$ for $n\ge100$.

Comment: @tess35 : I have added some numerical and graphical illustrations of Uspensky's approximation.

Comment: @tess35 : Are you now satisfied with the answer? If so, here are the pertinent [guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I was locked on  k <n/2 and see the error grow, but it's better for k >n/2,  clearly the error is very low, shrink and we could take $ f= 2^n - ur(x)$ for $k\leq n/2 $  And the formula is easy. So i think this topic is closed.